# How to deal with exporting multiple images from the Compositing afterward rendering is completed?

Tags: compositing-nodes

How to deal with exporting multiple images from the Compositing afterward rendering is completed? Render result as a bunch of multiple images we can automatically save by employing File Output node but the node is useless for exporting when the render is already completed. There should be a way which I apparently don't know to save all outputs that I want from the Compositing in on go.

For instance, if I have made numerous masks by the Cryptomatte node  and want to save them all as separate images from the Compositing I should plug each to the Viewer node and go to "Save as" menu but it is crazy if should repeat the same for each mask

Answer (score -1):

Save it to EXR multilayer. This format allows storing all passes in one file.

[image]

Comment: Nope, connecting outputs of the "CryptoMatte" nodes to the "Viewer" node is impossible to save the MultiLayer file

Comment: You don't have to